# Pipeline keeps failing in Azure Synapse (running a simple query)

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am learning how to create pipelines with the help of a Udemy course in Azure Synapse. I created a link service that connects to my 'master' database of my serverless SQL pool. The connection itself was successful:

[image]

I then created a simple 'script activity' in the Pipeline which connects to this linked service and then returns a query.

[image]

Here is the full query I used (I masked some of the data):

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *, result.filename()
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/taxi/raw/trip_data_green_parquet/year=*/month=*/*.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    )  
    WITH (
        VendorID INT, 
        lpep_pickup_datetime datetime2(7)
        )   AS [result]
```

It should be noted that the above query works fine when I run  it outside of the pipeline. I then clicked 'validate' to check for errors and no errors were found:

[image]

But when I clicked 'Debug' it failed:

[image]

Here is the full error code:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Argument {0} is null or empty.\r\nParameter name: paraKey",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Script1",
    "details": []
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried running the following SQL query and it worked:

```
SELECT
    TOP 10 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/taxi/raw/taxi_zone_without_header.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) 
   WITH(
        LocationID SMALLINT 1,
        Borough VARCHAR(15) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 2,
        service_zone VARCHAR(15) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 4,
        Zone VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 3
    ) AS [result]
```

I'm not too sure why the other one did not work.

Comment: This error is because there is no column name for results.filename() in the SQL script. Try giving `result.filename() as file_name` in the script.

Comment: I just tried to run this and it gave me the following error: {
    "errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'result'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'result'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Script1",
    "details": []
}

Comment: Did you give comma after top10 *? `top 10 *, result.filename() as filename`

Comment: Solved. It works now. I had forgotten to include the ] bracket at the very end. So your suggestion of naming the column for results.filename() solved my issue. Thank you very much!. Please include it in the answer area so that I could mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Argument {0} is null or empty.\r\nParameter name: paraKey"

This error is because there is no column name for results.filename() in the SQL script. Try giving `result.filename() as file_name` in the script.

I repro'd this without alias name for filename() function and got the same error.

[image]

- Then column name is added in script and synapse pipeline is run successfully.

[image]

**SQL script:**

```sql
SELECT
    TOP 100 *, result.filename() as file_name
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/taxi/raw/trip_data_green_parquet/year=*/month=*/*.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    )  
    WITH (
        VendorID INT, 
        lpep_pickup_datetime datetime2(7)
        )   AS [result]
```